# To find a list of possible sub array from a array

Tags: python, arraylist

I am struggling to find a way to get all possible sublist from a list
like Consider a list **[1,2,3,4]**
i want sublists like

```
sublists = [[1, 2, 3, 4]],[[1], [2, 3, 4]],[[1, 2], [3, 4]],[[1], [2], [3, 4]],[[1, 2, 3], [4]],[[1], [2, 3], [4]],[[1, 2], [3], [4]],[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Please tell if there any way of doing this

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @IoaTzimas yes i have tried doing `lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lstt = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    l1 = []
    l2 = lst[i:]
    l3 = lst[:i]
    l1.append(l2)
    l1.append(l3)
    lstt.append(l1)
print(lstt)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to pick start and end of your sublist:

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

sublists = [ lst[i:j] for i,j in combinations(range(len(lst)+1),r=2) ]
```

yields:

```
[[1],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 5],
 [3],
 [3, 4],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [4],
 [4, 5],
 [5]]
```

Comment: brother i does not want this as a result , i am expecting sublists containing every value from main list

Comment: which sublist do you think is missing here?

Comment: i want something like 'For list like [1,2,3,4]   i want           [  [1, 2, 3, 4]  ],[  [1], [2, 3, 4]  ],[  [1, 2], [3, 4]  ],[ 
 [1], [2], [3, 4]  ],[  [1, 2, 3], [4]  ],[  [1], [2, 3], [4]  ],[  [1, 2], [3], [4]  ],[  [1], [2], [3], [4]  ]'

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
def  sub_lists (l):
    lists = []
    for i in range(len(l) + 1):
        l2=[]
        for j in range(i):
            l2.append(l[j: i])
        lists.append(l2.copy())
        l2.clear()
    return lists
l1 = [1, 2, 3,4,5]
print(sub_lists(l1))
```

Comment: :( @LoneWolf, I will try

Comment: please try once

Answer (score 0):

You could think of this as a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem. Starting with a set `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, we can choose to place a bar between any two elements, e.g. `1 | 2 3 | 4`, corresponding to subsets `[1], [2, 3], [4]`. There are `n-1` places where a bar can be placed, resulting `2^(n-1)` distinct placements. Here is a way to do this using `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

def subsets(xs):
  n = len(xs)
  inds = list(range(1,n))
  for bs in product([True, False], repeat=len(inds)):
    cutoffs = [0] + [i for i, b in zip(inds, bs) if b] + [n] 
    zs = zip(cutoffs, cutoffs[1:])
    yield [xs[i:j] for i, j in zs]

list(subsets([1,2,3,4]))
# [[[1], [2], [3], [4]],
#  [[1], [2], [3, 4]],
#  [[1], [2, 3], [4]],
#  [[1], [2, 3, 4]],
#  [[1, 2], [3], [4]],
#  [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
#  [[1, 2, 3], [4]],
#  [[1, 2, 3, 4]]]
```